# Extjs6 Custom button with custom config binding

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I've created a custom button(extend from Ext.button.Button). The new custom button has a new span in the template and a new config.

This custom button is used in a toolbar docked on a grid.

```
{
    xtype: 'customButton',
    text: 'Custom button',
    //customConfig: 5    //this line works
    bind:{
        customConfig: '{customConfigData}',
        lazy: false
    },
    listeners: {
        click: function(btn, ev){
            debugger
        }
    }
}
```

The grid is a child of an container.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myview.MyView', {
        extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
        xtype: 'main-view',
        requires: [
            'MyApp.view.myview.MyGrid'
        ],
        viewModel: {
            type: 'myModel'
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Home',
            layout: 'fit',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'myGrid',
                    margin: '10 0 0 0'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    });
```

The container has a view model attached. Inside the view model I, in the data section I've added new value.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myview.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.myModel',
    data: {
        customConfigData: 99
    },
    stores: {
        users: {
            type: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to bind the custom config of my custom button with the value in the view model but with no success. I read that by default all the configs are bindable but in my case somehow, the custom button config doesn't sees the view model.

I've created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21to). Here you can also find my full custom button code.

What is the prop way to bind to a custom config?

Comment: In future if you're going to post a test case, leave out all the extraneous stuff.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Can you please highlight some extraneous stuff? I did not understand to what stuff you refer to

Comment: The stores, models, grid are all irrelevant for a start. The whole thing could easily be reduced to a single file of about 30-40 lines to get the point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things, both of which go in your button class:

1) Add an updater for the config to react to changes:

```
updateCustomConfig: function(v) {
    this.innerSpan.setHtml(v);
}
```

2) To facilitate #1, use `childEls` to allow your component to have an easy reference to `innerSpan`:

```
childEls: ['innerSpan']
```

Comment: Working example: [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21u0)